# How does the merge() in merge_sort() work?

Tags: c, merge

So I was looking at the C example of merge sort on Rosetta Code and I'm a bit confused about how the merge() function works. I think it is the syntax they use that throws me off with the colons and ?'s.

```
void merge (int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]
             : i == m      ? a[j++]
             : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]
             :               a[i++];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
    free(x);
}

void merge_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int m = n / 2;
    merge_sort(a, m);
    merge_sort(a + m, n - m);
    merge(a, n, m);
}
```

What exactly is happening in the for loop of the merge() function? Can someone explain it please?

Comment: It is called the conditional (or sometimes ternary) operator. You can read about it [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/1AUq5Di1/).

Comment: And in a word, this one operates poorly.  There is no need to copy the high side of the sequence to temp storage if the low side finishes first. What is left on the high side is already in-place in the original array.

Comment: Wow, I honestly don't see why the code is written that way. That seems way too complicated for a simple merge routine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the comments:

```
void merge (int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    // inefficient: allocating a temporary array with malloc 
    // once per merge phase!
    int *x = malloc(n * sizeof (int));
    // merging left and right halfs of a into temporary array x
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; k < n; k++) {
        x[k] = j == n      ? a[i++]  // right half exhausted, take from left
             : i == m      ? a[j++]  // left half exhausted, take from right
             : a[j] < a[i] ? a[j++]  // right element smaller, take that
             :               a[i++]; // otherwise take left element
    }
    // copy temporary array back to original array.
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = x[i];
    }
    free(x);   // free temporary array
}

void merge_sort (int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int m = n / 2;
    // inefficient: should not recurse if n == 2
    // recurse to sort left half
    merge_sort(a, m);
    // recurse to sort right half
    merge_sort(a + m, n - m);
    // merge left half and right half in place (via temp array)
    merge(a, n, m);
}
```

A simpler and more efficient version of the `merge` function, using only half as much temporary space:

```
static void merge(int *a, int n, int m) {
    int i, j, k;
    int *x = malloc(m * sizeof (int));
    // copy left half to temporary array
    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        x[i] = a[i];
    }
    // merge left and right half
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0; i < m && j < n; k++) {
        a[k] = a[j] < x[i] ? a[j++] : x[i++];
    }
    // finish copying left half
    while (i < m) {
        a[k++] = x[i++];
    }
}
```

A faster version of `merge_sort` involves allocating a temporary array `x` of size `n * sizeof(*a)` and passing it to a recursive function `merge_sort1` that calls `merge` with as extra parameter as well.  The logic in `merge` is also improved here with half as many comparisons on `i` and `j`:

```
static void merge(int *a, int n, int m, int *x) {
    int i, j, k;

    for (i = 0; i < m; i++) {
        x[i] = a[i];
    }
    for (i = 0, j = m, k = 0;;) {
        if (a[j] < x[i]) {
            a[k++] = a[j++];
            if (j >= n) break;
        } else {
            a[k++] = x[i++];
            if (i >= m) return;
        }
    }
    while (i < m) {
        a[k++] = x[i++];
    }
}

static void merge_sort1(int *a, int n, int *x) {
    if (n >= 2) {
        int m = n / 2;
        if (n > 2) {
            merge_sort1(a, m, x);
            merge_sort1(a + m, n - m, x);
        }
        merge(a, n, m, x);
    }
}

void merge_sort(int *a, int n) {
    if (n < 2)
        return;
    int *x = malloc(n / 2 * sizeof (int));
    merge_sort1(a, n, x);
    free(x);
}
```

Comment: So excuse me if I'm wrong, but Mergesort looks a LOT like Quicksort... how are they different exactly?

Comment: `mergesort` and `qsort` resemblance is limited: they both use recursion on a partition of the data.  `mergesort` systematically splits the data set in 2 halfs of equal size and merges them in linear time, yielding a complexity of *O(n.log(n))*, worst case and average case, is a stable sort, but requires *O(n)* working space.  `qsort` uses a heuristic to split the data set and sorts the parts in place.  It needs very little extra space, has an average case complexity of *O(n.log(n))*, but It is unstable and has a worst case complexity of *O(n^2)*, that can be problematic.